# Bash script, get number of physical cores as number and iterate

Tags: bash, cpu, script

I wrote a script that shows a number of physical cores of the machine. However, I would like the result to be a number, not a string.

Here's the script:

```
phycores=echo $sudoPW | cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -m 1 "cpu cores" | awk '{print $ 4;}'
echo $phycores  

for i in {1..$phycores}
do
   echo "Core $i"
done
```

Comment: `bash` convert on the fly strings to numbers. so you should not concern about this

Comment: But why am I getting a newline while trying to echo the `$phycores`? It shows 2 [Enter], not only 2

Comment: What do you mean by "physical cores"? What you're trying to extract from `cpuinfo` may not be what you want. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146051/108618).

Comment: bash doesn't have the notion of numbers. Everything is a string or an array of strings.

Comment: @BrianBrown If you only need the "number" then strip the trailing newline `\n\r`, `\n`

Answer (score 1):

I'm spotting a few issues:

- Why the `echo $sudoPW` piped to cat? cat ignores it without a `-` somewhere.
- And `$phycores` doesn't get set without backticks or `$()` that can't be the actual script you're running, and it still sets $phycores to a number with a newline?
- The `{1..n}` construct doesn't work with a variable, if your `$phycores` were 4 then it just sets the `$i` variable to `{1..4}`. [See this Q on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash) for more details. (A newline in `$phycores` shouldn't matter)

Anyway, this should be a more working script

```
phycores=$(echo $sudoPW|cat - /proc/cpuinfo|grep -m 1 "cpu cores"|awk '{print $ 4;}')

echo $phycores  

for ((i=1;i<=phycores;++i))
do
   echo "Core $i"
done
```

Comment: In absence of a Linux tag, :) I'll add the (simpler) FreeBSD equivalent: phycores=$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)